# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have been looking at this for a while and can't see where the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
[WebMethod(true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string neighbourhoodTeam(string force, string neighbourhood) 
{
    //StreamManager streamMan = new StreamManager();
    //return streamMan.StreamManagerUrlHandler("http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/" + force + "%2F" + neighbourhood + "%2F" + "people");
    return neighbourhood + force;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function getOfficers(force, neighbourhood) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../police/crimerequest.aspx/neighbourhoodTeam",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "force": force, "neighbourhood": neighbourhood }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var results = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            $.each(results, function (i) {
                businessCards.push(generateOfficerBusinessCard(
                            results[i].name,
                            results[i].rank,
                            results[i].contact_details.mobile,
                            results[i].contact_details.tel,
                            results[i].contact_details.email))
            });
            PoliceApp.businessCardsPlaceHolder.html(businessCards.toString());
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And I get:`{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027force\u0027.","StackTrace":"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sending with `processData: false` in your ajax params. jQuery will stringify again by default.

Use fiddler or similar tool to inspect network traffic and see what is getting actually sent to your web service.

Comment: I removed the stringify and allowed jquery to process data. what is being sent to the service is: force sussex neighbourhood CC2NH7 but now I get invalid json primitive.

Comment: Try this: stringify yourself, and set processData to false.

Comment: I stringify myself and set the processData to false. what I get now is {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027force\u0027.","StackTrace":"  The Params sent are now: {"force":"sussex","neighb...

Comment: Should I be renaming aspx of the service as asmx?

Comment: Good catch! I didn't notice that earlier. Change it to asmx. Are you using any tools like fiddler? ALso, if you attach a debugger, does it come to your method or it throws the exception even before that?

Comment: Now its all working but only locally and I get “401 Unauthorized” on the server. I hope its not becuase I haven't included <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory"
                 validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers> if this is the issue how can I get around it without adding it. its a shared server and doesn't let me add httpmodules

Comment: I am also calling the service from a normal html page not an aspx. is this an issue?

Comment: Calling it from html should no be an issue. The other problem you have should be a separate question (I'm not an expert but I guess it should be).